# блокируется работа с git в visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, git, github

в окне Team explorer пишет:

> в репозитории "..." выполняется операция перемещения изменений из одной ветви в другую. Эту операцию необходимо продолжить из командной строки.

и ничего нельзя сделать! причём нельзя зафиксировать никакие изменения только через visual studio, через GitHub desktop всё работает.

как завершить эту операцию если при открытии командной строки просто открывается командная строка? или как отменить эту операцию?

Comment: "при открытии командной строки просто открывается командная строка"? Выполните в ком. строке в директории проекта необходимые git-команды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Операция перемещения изменений" - похоже на git rebase. Попробуйте запустить
git rebase --abort